# Как оставить из строки только то, что между определенными символами на PHP?

Tags: php

Как оставить из `<img src="/images/image.jpg"><img src="/images/defimage1.jpg">` только то, что между `src=""`? Чтобы в итоге получилось лишь `/images/image.jpg/images/defimage1.jpg`

Comment: Может, вам стоит html-парсер взять?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

я думаю у вас для этого есть два варианта.

через регулярное выражение

```
$str = '<img src="/images/image.jpg"><img src="/images/defimage1.jpg">';
$regex = '/src="([^"]*)"/i';
preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);

var_dump( $matches[1] );
```

через DOMDocument

```
$str = '<img src="/images/image.jpg"><img src="/images/defimage1.jpg">';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);

foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $item ){
    var_dump( $item->getAttribute('src') );
}
```